# I've gone to the gym three times a week vs I've been going to the gym three times a week

Tags: grammar, meaning

What's the difference in meaning between

> I've been going to the gym three times a week.

And

> I've gone to the gym three times a week.

I think the first started in the past and continues into the present.

Does the second one mean the same?

I'm not sure the second one makes sense. I've gone to the gym three times this week makes more sense. "A week" sounds like a current habit but I've gone sounds Finish, not current.

Comment: Not at all. I'm not comparing "gone to" with "been to". I'm asking about gone to the gym as a regular activity not an outing.

Comment: Not at all. The-baby-is-you has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I've been going to the gym three times a week**: You've been going to the gym regularly starting at a recent point and continuing through the present.

**I've gone to the gym three times a week**: Ill-formed without more information. Usually "I've done X" on its own means you've done it at least once in the past, but "three times a week" refers to a continuing habit, so they can't really go together.

Some alternatives:

- I've gone to the gym three times *this* week: You've been there three times in the current week. It's possible, but not necessary, that you could go more times.
- I've gone to the gym three times *in* a week: There's been at least one week in your life that included three gym visits. (In practice, could be used to mean the same as above.)
- I've gone to the gym three times a week *every summer since 2015*: With a duration, the past perfect makes sense.